# Juju-core upgraded, how to connect to runing environment?

Tags: juju, maas

I just run

> apt-get install —only-upgrade juju-core

which cut me off from my Juju/Openstack running environment! Even the environments.yaml and maas.jenv files are still at same place with the same content. But now with $juju status, it tells me there is no environment, i should bootstrap a new one!

Does bootstrap really launch a new one and rewrite everything or i get "back" to my running environment?

I see, that all charms and GUIs are working just fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was, that when ive started to mess with the update, i switched to root user. And then, still as root, i did the $juju status and other commands..

Once im back at my user, it works fine.

uf. A massive rock felt from my heart.

It might be useful for somebody else in future.